# Binary Search in MongoDB array without index

Tags: mongodb

Ok, so I have a very big number of documents in a sharded collection, let's say 1million. Each document holds a SORTED array of documents of size 10000.

In order to access the top-level documents fastly, MongoDB uses the shard order plus the index to quickly find the document in question. Nonetheless, once I reach the document, then I have to look which set of sub-documents(in the array) satisfy my query. Now, I know this array is sorted but MongoDB doesn't. Also, creating 1Million indices is too expensive.

Therefore, my question is the following, is there a way to force MongoDB to binary search a sorted array without an index?

Answer (score 0):

I think that using $where and passing in some custom javascript is your only hope:
https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/where/